# Where to ask which similar programs already exist (when developing a program)?

Tags: discussion, scope

My problem:

I'm planning to write a certain program and I didn't see any similar program up to now. However I suppose that similar programs already exist.

I already searched in the internet but I didn't find any similar software.

I'd like to know if/which similar programs already exist.

My question:

Would such a question ("which programs do have such a feature") be on-topic on this or another SE network site?

(On StackOverflow I was told that this site would be the correct one but I have my doubts about that.)

Comment: Have you actually started writing the program? Or not at all yet?

Comment: Related (but different) questions: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131/what-are-the-rules-for-self-answering-your-question https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/acceptable-to-ask-%e2%86%92-build-%e2%86%92-self-answer-a-question-for-open-source

Answer (score 2):

Your doubts are partly correct – that is, if asking the question with that background (which looks a bit like you either just want to investigate its code, or compare it with your application).

It would hovewer be on-topic if you asked for a program meeting specific requirements. After all, you need an application that meets certain requirements – and if one exists that perfectly matches, you wouldn't need to write it – because, why reinventing the wheel?